# libjpeg decode nv12 or yuv420p

Tags: libjpeg

I'm trying to get a YUV420 palanar or semiplanar (NV12) image out of jpeg using libjpeg.

I see that there is a option to specify output format to JCS_YCbCr which would generally be a YUV format, but as far as i understand it would give me the data as arrays of 3 elements { Y, U, V }. So to get the image to the right format i would have to rearange and subsample the pixels myself and i want to avoid that for performance reasons.

So I was wondering is there a way to configure libjpeg to output a YUV420p / NV12 buffer directly.

Answer (score 3):

Just take a look at `gst_jpeg_decode()` in gstreamer source tree. This function along with `gst_jpeg_decode_direct()` function does exactly what you want to do.

Note that it gives YUV420 planar output, bypassing all color conversion done by libjpeg. (Note: this assumes that the input JPEG is encoded in YUV420 color space (aka I420), which is true for almost all JPEGs out there.